# Moving ctor not kicking-in

Tags: c++, move-semantics

following code

```
#include <iostream>

class C
{
public:
    C(int i) : i{i}{ }
    C(const C&) = delete;  // no copy allowed
    C(C&& c){ std::cout << "moving from " << c.i << '\n'; i = c.i--; }
    int i;
};

void func(C&& c) { std::cout << "func c " << c.i << '\n'; }

int main()
{
    C c{123};
    func(std::move(c));
    std::cout << "c " << c.i;
}
```

outputs

```
func c 123
c 123
```

so moving ctor is not kicking-in: why?

Additional question: given

```
void func(C&& c1, C&& c2) { ... }
```

is legal calling it twice using same argument?

```
func(std::move(c), std::move(c));
```

I would say no, since, independently from which argument is evaluated first, it should not be legal to move when evaluating the other one. But:

```
void func(C&& c1, C&& c2) { std::cout << "func c1 " << c1.i << "  c2 " << c2.i << '\n'; }

int main()
{
    C c{123};
    func(std::move(c), std::move(c));
    std::cout << "c " << c.i;
}
```

outputs

```
func c1 123  c2 123
c 123
```

so moving ctor is not kicking-in again.

Comment: the moving constructor is not called because there is no need to create any new object, if you change your function func to take an object instead of an universal reference the counter will be decreased

Comment: `std::move` doesn't actually move the object but casts it (if possible) into an r-value reference the object can be moved from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::move` doesn't actually call the move constructor. It is a cast to r-value reference (akin to `static_cast<C&&>(c)`). Once this is done, if you try to copy that object, it will call the move-constructor or the move-assignment operator. If you don't try to copy that object, nothing happens. Try this:

```
// By value
void func(C c) { std::cout << "func c " << c.i << '\n'; }

// By r-value reference
void func2(C&& c)
{
    C c1{std::move(c)};
    std::cout << "func2 c " << c.i << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    C c{123};
    func(std::move(c));
    func2(std::move(c));
    std::cout << "c " << c.i;
}
```

Comment: I got the point, ty.
So, considering that copying C is not allowed, to have move ctor to kick-in I must either:
take argument by copy in `func(C c){ ... }` which must be invoked as `func(move(c));` or **move** argument(s) **inside** `func(C&& c){ C c1{std::move(c)}; ... }`

Is this correct?

Comment: @user1832484 that is correct. The function should be invoked like `func(move(c));` in both cases.